# GPS based Alarm Application in Android

Tags: android, gps

I want to create an application like:

1. I am in city X
2. I want to get notification(like ringing alarm or vibration etc) when I reach city Y.

I already have sqlite database containing information(latitude, longitude) about many cities.

I have searched Google and SO but didn't find proper solution.

So far my research says this:

What I have to do is to create a `Service` or `BroadcastReceiver` to get current location of the mobile phone using GPS.

Correct me if I am going wrong.

I want to get current position of mobile phone at an interval of 10mins. And based on that latitude longitude values I will compare that with the Scheduled city latitude longitude.

If match occurs then it should give notification to user.

Things that I have done:

1. I know how to get current location of user. (But not by creating service. Thats what I wanted to know! )
2. I am able to add tasks in sqlite database.

Please guide me how can I approach for this application.

Starting it when the user launches the application:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context, MyLocationApps.class);     
 context.startService(i);
```

---

```
public class MyLocationApps extends Service{

        LocationManager locMan;
        Location curLocation;
        Boolean locationChanged;

        LocationListener gpsListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // Log.w("GPS", "Started");
                if (curLocation == null) {
                        curLocation = location;
                        locationChanged = true;
                }

                if (curLocation.getLatitude() == location.getLatitude() && curLocation.getLongitude() == location.getLongitude())
                        locationChanged = false;
                else
                        locationChanged = true;

                curLocation = location;

                if (locationChanged)
                        locMan.removeUpdates(gpsListener);

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // Log.w("GPS", "Location changed", null);
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle extras) {
                if (status == 0)// UnAvailable
                {

                } else if (status == 1)// Trying to Connect
                {

                } else if (status == 2) {// Available

                }
        }

};


       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Inside onCreate of Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               Log.e(TAG, "Inside onCreate of Service");
               super.onCreate();

               locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
               locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0, 0, gpsListener);
               /*if (locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                       locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,20000, 1, gpsListener);
               } else {
                       this.startActivity(new Intent("android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS"));
               }
*/
               if (curLocation != null) {
                       double lat = curLocation.getLatitude();
                       double lng = curLocation.getLongitude();
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Lat : " + String.valueOf(lat) + "\n Long : "+ String.valueOf(lng), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }
               else
               {
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Didn Get any location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
       }

        final String TAG="LocationService";
        @Override
       public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Inside onStartCommand of Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 Log.e(TAG, "Inside onStartCommand of Service");



                 return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
       }
       @Override
       public void onLowMemory() {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               super.onLowMemory();
       }


          @Override
          public void onStart(Intent i, int startId)
          {
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Inside onStart of Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             Log.e(TAG, "Inside onStart of Service");


      }

          public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Inside onBind of Service");
                     return null;
          }
}
```

**Problem in code**

When i run the application for the first time, it displays Toast Messages.
But it never displays a Toast Message even i send location thru DDMS..

Where i am going wrong can you please tell me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got it working : (Thanks to Ganapathy & Farhan )

```
public class MyLocationApps extends Service{

LocationManager locMan;
Location curLocation;
Boolean locationChanged;

Handler handler = new Handler();

LocationListener gpsListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Log.w("GPS", "Started");
            if (curLocation == null) {
                    curLocation = location;
                    locationChanged = true;
            }

            if (curLocation.getLatitude() == location.getLatitude() && curLocation.getLongitude() == location.getLongitude())
                    locationChanged = false;
            else
                    locationChanged = true;

            curLocation = location;

            if (locationChanged) 
                    locMan.removeUpdates(gpsListener);

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // Log.w("GPS", "Location changed", null);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
            if (status == 0)// UnAvailable
            {

            } else if (status == 1)// Trying to Connect
            {

            } else if (status == 2) {// Available

            }
    }

};


   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Inside onCreate of Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           Log.e(TAG, "Inside onCreate of Service");
           super.onCreate();

           locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
           locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0, 0, gpsListener);
           /*if (locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                   locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,20000, 1, gpsListener);
           } else {
                   this.startActivity(new Intent("android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS"));
           }
 */
           if (curLocation != null) {
                   double lat = curLocation.getLatitude();
                   double lng = curLocation.getLongitude();
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Lat : " + String.valueOf(lat) + "\n Long : "+ String.valueOf(lng), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           }
           else
           {
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Didn Get any location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
   }

    final String TAG="LocationService";
    @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Inside onStartCommand of Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             Log.e(TAG, "Inside onStartCommand of Service");



             return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
   }
   @Override
   public void onLowMemory() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           super.onLowMemory();
   }


  @Override
  public void onStart(Intent i, int startId)
  {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Inside onStart of Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     Log.e(TAG, "Inside onStart of Service");

     handler.postDelayed(GpsFinder,5000);// will start after 5 seconds
  }

  public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Inside onBind of Service");
             return null;
  }
  public Runnable GpsFinder = new Runnable()
  {

    public void run()
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           if (locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            {

                locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0, 0, gpsListener);
            }
            else
            {
                    getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent("android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS"));
            }

            if (curLocation != null) {
                    double lat = curLocation.getLatitude();
                    double lng = curLocation.getLongitude();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Lat : " + String.valueOf(lat) + "\n Long : "+ String.valueOf(lng), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            handler.postDelayed(GpsFinder,5000);// register again to start after 5 seconds...


    }
  };
 }
```

Comment: I thought, this GPS alarm could be a new idea for me to implement. But you have implemented it before me!!! Can we get GPS value for a place (when I keep my mobile phone in that place) without internet connection?

Comment: yes. you will have to make use of Network Location(cell tower location).

Comment: Thanks. Have you come across any such GPS alarm application for Android - ready to download and free to use?

Comment: Yes. I have developed such application. But didnot put it in Google Play.. You will find lots of app. on Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the code here : [android-mycycle/MyLocationManager.java](http://android-mycycle.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/android-mycycle/trunk/src/com/va/mycycle/MyLocationManager.java?revision=14&view=markup)

I have implemented this for my application. I am trying to get a gps fix before I start receiving the location.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using `Geofence` along with `intentservice`. Refer the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) for more information.